# Is there something like IIS 6.0 Resource Kit Tools for IIS 7?

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, iis-metabase

Is there something like [IIS 6.0 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/993a8a36-5761-448f-889e-9ae58d072c09.mspx?mfr=true) for IIS 7, specially the metabase explorer tool to be able to edit the IIS configurations without editing the .xml and .config files directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Configuration Editor built-in IIS 7.5 (Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2), which can also be downloaded for IIS 7.0 (Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008) from http://www.iis.net/download/AdministrationPack

(See the video in the URL above, minute 1:25 shows the tool).

Comment: Seams exactly what I am looking for, but for example I have a case in which I need to edit the maxAllowedContentLength in the IIS, where to find this in this tool?

Comment: If you know the section, then you can just select that in the combo box, however, if you do not know the section name, I usually just open %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\schema\iis_schema.xml and search for the attribute in there. You will find the sectionSchema element and you will see the name attribute, that is the one you will need to select.